# How to visualize "list progress" in Sharepoint/Teams

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, microsoft-teams, power-automate, powerapps

We have a list with actions with a due date and a status. We'd like to visualize this list as a timeline with progress shown as green when on time and status "done"and red when over due and still in progress or not started.

We'd like to have this list in TEAMS and the status report in sharepoint.

Should this be done with Power Automate or what tech do you think of here?

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to create a timeline with progress in Teams and SharePoint is to use Microsoft Lists and Microsoft Planner. You can create a list in Teams using the Lists app, and then add a timeline view to visualize your tasks and their due dates. You can also sync your list with Planner to create a task board and track the status of each task. You can then embed your list or your planner board in a SharePoint page to share it with others.